# How to add multiple test conditions in 'test' attribute expression of <xsl:if> tag

Tags: xslt, xpath

Is there any possibility  to include multiple conditions in 'test' attribute expression in `<xsl:if>` tag of XSLT like

```
<xsl:if test="$var='ab' | $var='bc' | $var='ca' ">
</xsl:if>
```

I am getting an error as
"Expression must be evaluated to a node-set".

Is there any possibility to code such multiple conditions in `<xsl:if>` Tag?

Can anyone explain how can we achieve this multiple condition validation for the following tags in

`<xsl:if>` in test attribute expression

`<xsl:for-each>` in select attribute expression

`<xsl:template>` in match attribute expression

?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:if test="$var='ab' | $var='bc' | $var='ca' ">
> ```

This is wrong -- you are using the XPath *union* operator `|` on boolean values.

**Solution**: use the XPath `or` operator:

```
<xsl:if test="$var='ab' or $var='bc' or $var='ca' ">
```

The above XPath expression (the value of the `test` attribute) can be optimized, so that only one comparison is made and no `or` is necessary:

```
<xsl:if test="contains('|ab|bc|ca|', concat('|', $var, '|'))">
```

Comment: so this is the same for the other tags right like for xsl:for-each and xsl:template

Comment: @Jeevan: You are welcome. Most XSLT instructions have attributes, whose value is specified as an XPath expression. The XPath language has its syntax rules and in any XPath expression `|` is the union operator.

Comment: Make sure they are lower case "and"/"or" - capitalized will not work.

Answer (score 7):

In XSLT 2.0 or above, you can test against a sequence of strings:

```
<xsl:if test="$var=('ab','bc','ca')">...</xsl:if>
```