# Test String Against Multiple Regex Expressions

Tags: xslt, xpath

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22252297/match-a-string-against-multiple-regex-patterns) question, I have an element that I'd like to test if it matches with a certain regex pattern. Currently, I'm doing something like this:

```
direction-type/words[matches(., '^cresc') or
            matches(., '^decresc') or matches(., '^diminuendo')]
```

However, now I'd like to add many more elements to this and make those elements easier to edit, perhaps by placing them all in a variable. I'd ideally like to do something like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10533209/1482644) solution, where you don't have to add a 'or' between each individual regex case:

```
<xsl:if test="contains('|ab|bc|ca|', concat('|', $var, '|'))">
```

How would I make something like that work with regex?

Comment: This might not work, but you could try using a regex pattern with an alternation: `matches(., '^(cresc|decresc|diminuendo)')`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did think about that, but I would have preferred a solution that is more versatile on the XSLT side (as in, you don't have to edit the regex directly). But you should type that up as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One pure regex approach would be to just use an alternation here:

```
matches(., '^(cresc|decresc|diminuendo)')
```